How to Define Parameters in a Central Shared Library in Jenkins
I'm using Jenkins 2.440.2. I want to be able to define all the parameters in a central place like Shared Library and reuse those parameters configuration in different Jenkinsfile.
// vars/commonParams.groovy
def getParams() {
    return [
        string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'Environment to deploy to'),
        booleanParam(name: 'RUN_TESTS', defaultValue: true, description: 'Run tests?')
    ]
}

// Jenkinsfile
@Library('my-shared-library') _
def param = commonParams.getParams()

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { param }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Environment: ${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
                echo "Run Tests: ${params.RUN_TESTS}"
            }
        }
    }
}

This throws an error:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 10: Expected a build parameter definition @ line 10, column 9.
           param
           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:635)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:581)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE


try parameters = param or parameters [ param ] or parameters(param) or parameters param or parameters([param]). I think parameters(param) should work, but I have no idea when groovy wants ( ) or not.

none of them worked,
parameters [param] gives an error :
WorkflowScript: 12: Not a valid section definition: "parameters [param]". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 12, column 5.
rest of them give the same error as above

I'm not sure this will work in a declarative syntax, at least like this.
What might work (I didn't have a chance to test it though) is the scripted definition of the parameters set by the properties before the pipeline:
// Jenkinsfile
@Library('my-shared-library') _

properties([
    parameters(
        commonParams.getParams()
    )
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Environment: ${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
                echo "Run Tests: ${params.RUN_TESTS}"
            }
        }
    }
}

I suppose it could be possible with pure declarative syntax, too, but most likely one would need to play with closures and other unobvious Jenkins Groovy concepts.
